# How to write a Python for loop as a lambda function with apply or map instead?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, apply

How would I write this code using a lambda function and apply or map? I have looked at several blog posts, etc., but for some reason I feel like I am missing something. I think it should be really simply.

```
for i in range(2,5):
    print(f'I only have {i} friends, but they are awesome.')

# I only have 2 friends, but they are awesome.
# I only have 3 friends, but they are awesome.
# I only have 4 friends, but they are awesome.
```

Comment: You wouldn't. A loop is the appropriate and preferred way to execute a series of statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop is good enough for this task, but if for some reason you must use lambda and map, you can do it like this:

```
list(map(lambda x: print(f"I only have {x} friends, but they are awesome."), range(2, 5)))
```

The expression needs to be wrapped in `list()` as the `map` function is eagerly executed, which means it doesn't calculate the output until it is needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I think what I was missing in my own attempt was the list(). And to clarify, the loop above was not the actual task I was doing but just a reproducible example haha. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you don't just use lambda or map to execute the above code, But if you want to achieve this with lambda or map only, you need to convert the map object into a list.

```
list(map(lambda x:print(f'I only have {x} friends, but they are awesome.'), range(2,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use lambdas at all, unreadable. Lambda expressions can't contain loops, statements. They can contain expressions only (think maths), However, Your problem can be approached like the following.

```
s = 'I only have {} friends, but they are awesome.'
f = lambda x: list(map(print, map(s.format, x)))
f([1, 2, 3])
```

We're calling list to force evaluate the result generator, note that it's called 3 times ([1, 2, 3]) and therefore, there're [None, None, None] returned. The result generator is basically mapping print function on a list that looks like [s.format(1), s.format(2), s.format(3)]

I wanted only to show you how to do it, but this is a very bad approach.

We can do the same with fstrings or percent %.